# Crash maybe because of pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("Test.mp3")
 
fenetre = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
 
 
continuer = 1
 
 
while continuer:
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

Except that after that my spyder interpreter (3.6) or the "console mode" crash and I do not know why.I've also try with wav file and without the sound, the script still crash
I'm starting to learn informatic and I hope you can help me solve my problem :D

Comment: maybe try launch your script from command prompt `/Users/.../.../anaconda/bin/python <<<your_pygame_script>>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pygame.event.pump()` in the inner while loop (and maybe in the main loop as well) or the program will "freeze" because the events are not handled.

```
while continuer:
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        pygame.event.pump()
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I can't close my window is it that the fault of .pump()?

Other question (sorry) : I've try to play the song  without the window and it don't work do you have any idea 
to solve this because I want use a tkinter window with a pygame sound in background but I don't want 2 window

Comment: I think I need to see your code (just a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). You can post it as a new question and write a comment here to notify me. I guess the while loops could cause some problems if you want to combine your pygame code with tkinter. BTW, you don't have to create a pygame display/window if you just want to play sounds or music.

Comment: "you don't have to create a pygame display/window if you just want to play sounds or music" I know, but without the sound don't work :D

Comment: I have a few tkinter programs with pygame sound/music and they work without a pygame window.